# How to truncate a UIImage in iOS

Tags: ios, ios4

How can I truncate the left side of an image stored in a UIImage object. Basically in certain situations I just want to show part of an image.

How can I do this on with the iOS sdk?

P.S. I tried changing the frame size of the UIImage but that just scales the image and distorts it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to crop a UIImage, you can use one of the UIImage categories available out there, such as http://www.hive05.com/2008/11/crop-an-image-using-the-iphone-sdk/

For example, this frame will remove 100 pixel from the left side of a 200x200 pixel UIImage

```
 CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 200);
 UIImage *cropped = [self imageByCropping:lightsOnImage toRect:clippedRect];
```

Comment: This works but about 1 or 2 pixels are getting chopped off the bottom. How can I fix this?

Comment: `CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 201);`

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way is to load the image into a `UIImageView`, and then add the view to another view. You can then position the image view so that its `.frame.origin.x` property is negative, which will place it off to the left. The parent view needs to have `setMasksToBounds:YES` called on it, or else the image view will still be fully-visible.

There are many other ways to achieve this effect as well, but this may be the simplest for you to implement.